# How to setup Gitlab ci stage with multiple shell commands

Tags: shell, gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

Given this example .Net CI pipeline configuration for Gitlab

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - |
        BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE="buildWarnings.log";
        
        dotnet build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:logFile=$BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE;warningsonly";
        
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ $(wc -l < $BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE) -gt 0 ]
        then
          # do stuff here
        fi
```

The pipeline fails because of invalid syntax. This is because it doesn't know there are multiple shell commands to execute.

This `.sh` file works on my local machine

```
#!/bin/bash

BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE="buildWarnings.log";

dotnet build --output build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:logFile=$BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE;warningsonly";

if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ $(wc -l < $BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE) -gt 0 ]
then
  # do stuff here
fi
```

so how can I embed it into a Gitlab ci stage correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Add your shell script into the image so you can execute it: (in your case that would require creating a new image based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0`)

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - bash /path/to/your/script.sh
```

2. Create the shell script at run-time (just echo the script into a shell file and make it executable)

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - echo "BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE="buildWarnings.log";\ndotnet build\n-consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:logFile=$BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE;warningsonly";\nif [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ $(wc -l < $BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE) -gt 0 ]\nthen\nfi" > my-bash.sh
      - chmod +X my-bash.sh
      - bash ./my-bash.sh
```

3. Use the proper syntax of multi-bash command. (note the dash after the pipe)

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - |-
        BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE="buildWarnings.log";
        
        dotnet build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:logFile=$BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE;warningsonly";
        
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ $(wc -l < $BUILD_WARNINGS_LOG_FILE) -gt 0 ]
        then
          # do stuff here
        fi
```

Comment: I prefer the third solution. Unfortunately this doesn't work because Gitlab thinks the script is a Powershell script ... at least I can see it in the error logs `In C:\Windows\TEMP\build_script975465063\script.ps1` but I will try to convert it to a PS script and try it out